# Does the mouse appear more than once?

Tags: delicious-emily-true-love

In the Delicious series of games, there is always a mouse that appears while you are playing in the level. If you manage to click on it, you get 100 extra dollars towards your daily total, and there is a trophy for finding the mouse in every level.

Does the mouse pop up more than once in the course of a level? Or if I miss clicking on it once, do I have to do the level over in order to see it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mice will pop-up several times in a level until you catch it. After that it won't show up again until the next level.